# Can't Call Widget From Another Widget but Can From Main

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to make a simple app, where I have a slider that controls a timer set value. The user then hits a start button to start the timer and stop button to stop the timer. I've created a timer_model, timer_control, and timer_view. The timer_model extends ChangeNotifier and timer_view and timer_control both return a Consumer for the TimerModel class. I observe this problem where if have home in my main provide TimerControl, I can debug my code. If I use TimerView I cannot. However, TimerView calls TimerControl. If I comment out TimerControl in TimerView, I can view/debug my code. I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with what I'm doing:

```
import 'package:controller_ui/models/timer_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'views/timer_view.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => TimerModel(),
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: TimerView(),
    );
  }
}
```

Model:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TimerModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Timer? timer;
  double userSetTime = 10;
  final int maxTimeSeconds = 180;
  int timerSetTime = 10;

  void setTime(int seconds) {
    userSetTime = seconds.toDouble();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void startCountdown() {
    if (timer != null && timer!.isActive) return;

    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (timerSetTime > 0) {
        timerSetTime--;
      } else {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void resetCountdown() {
    timerSetTime =
        userSetTime.round(); // reset to initial value or any desired value
    timer?.cancel();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Control:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../models/timer_model.dart';

class TimerControl extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerControl({super.key});

  @override
  TimerControlState createState() => TimerControlState();
}

class TimerControlState extends State<TimerControl> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TimerModel>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 100,
                  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 12, 61),
                  child: Text(
                    value.userSetTime.round().toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                Slider(
                  value: value.userSetTime,
                  max: value.maxTimeSeconds.toDouble(),
                  label: value.userSetTime.round().toString(),
                  onChanged: (double seconds) {
                    value.setTime(seconds.round());
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

View:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../widgets/timer_control.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../models/timer_model.dart';

class TimerView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerView({super.key});

  @override
  State<TimerView> createState() => _TimerViewState();
}

class _TimerViewState extends State<TimerView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TimerModel>(
        builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TimerControl(),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 200,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: value.startCountdown,
                          child: const Text('Start')),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: value.resetCountdown,
                          child: const Text('Stop')),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct variable, which will be `value.timerSetTime` instead of `userSetTime`, and forgot to notify the listener after decrement.   Also, you don't need to have nested Scaffold, and try using `Provider.of` to call a method inside onPressed.

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => TimerModel(),
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: TimerView(),
    );
  }
}

class TimerModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Timer? timer;
  double userSetTime = 10;
  final int maxTimeSeconds = 180;
  int timerSetTime = 10;

  void setTime(int seconds) {
    userSetTime = seconds.toDouble();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void startCountdown() {
    if (timer != null && timer!.isActive) return;

    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (timerSetTime > 0) {
        timerSetTime--;
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void resetCountdown() {
    timerSetTime =
        userSetTime.round(); // reset to initial value or any desired value
    timer?.cancel();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class TimerControl extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerControl({super.key});

  @override
  TimerControlState createState() => TimerControlState();
}

class TimerControlState extends State<TimerControl> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TimerModel>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 100,
                backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 12, 61),
                child: Text(
                  value.timerSetTime.round().toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Slider(
                value: value.userSetTime,
                max: value.maxTimeSeconds.toDouble(),
                label: value.userSetTime.round().toString(),
                onChanged: (double seconds) {
                  value.setTime(seconds.round());
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class TimerView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerView({super.key});

  @override
  State<TimerView> createState() => _TimerViewState();
}

class _TimerViewState extends State<TimerView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const TimerControl(),
          const SizedBox(width: 200),
          Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Provider.of<TimerModel>(context, listen: false)
                        .startCountdown();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Start')),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Provider.of<TimerModel>(context, listen: false)
                      .resetCountdown();
                },
                child: const Text('Stop'),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah that helped a lot, thank you!  I also forgot timerSetTime = userSetTime.round(); in setTime(). Why specifically is Provider.of needed?

Comment: It is recommended by the author, if I remember it correctly.